# Changing color of a single barr in QBarSet

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Is that possible to set color for each bar within a single QBarSet?

```
QBarSet *set0 = new QBarSet("Jane");
*set0 << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6;

QHorizontalBarSeries *series = new QHorizontalBarSeries();

series->append(set0);
QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->addSeries(series);
```

Comment: Every `QBarSet` is independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `QBarSet` is independent. You could create a QList and iterate over them, and use the  [setColor()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbarset.html#setColor). For example:

```
QList<QBarSet *> barsets;
barsets.append(set0);
[...]

QColor color("blue");
for(auto barset: barsets){
    barset->setColor(color);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that set color for all bars within set0 ?

Comment: Every `QBarSet` is independent

Comment: Yes, it's independent, but a series of bars inside of it are all tight to this QBarSet parent. It came to me that the solution can be creating a lot of sets with a single bar inside and then doing what you suggested.